# Java Selenium throwing java.lang.NullPointerException:

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

I am trying to create Hybrid framework in POM with Java and selenium. but when i am trying to execute my test case it i throwing "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "com.TestCase.loginPageTest.driver" is null"
I ahve declared my driver as public static but still my issue occurs again. I am sharing my project structure and code snipets. please note i am using seleium 4.11 and my chrome version is 116[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Yd6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nog8I.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JriaM.png)

Can abyone can guide me how to resolve. PLease feel free to connect